# Find all indices of each letter in a string

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to get a list consisting of the indexes for each item of another sequence. 
Sounds easy enough in theory.

```
a = 'string of letters'
b = [a.index(x) for x in a]
```

But it doesn't work. I've tried list comprehensions, simple for loops, using enumerate etc, but every time b will return the same index for duplicates in a. 
That is, 's' in a, for example, will return '0' in b for both the first and last item because they're the same character. 
I'm guessing is cache or something like that as a way for Python to speed things up.

In any case, I can't figure this out and I'd appreciate some help as to how I can get this working as well as maybe an explanation of why this happens.

Comment: Can you clarify what you’re trying to do?

Comment: @usr2564301 done

Comment: @AMC A Caesar Cipher, that 'encodes' a text according a certain character shift (a shift of 3, 4, 7 etc characters). but I'd made it so that the result was returned in lowercase and wanted to somehow keep uppercase characters in the input the same in the output as well

Comment: Ah, well that seems quite different from the rest of your post. How does the issue with indexes above play into this?

Comment: well, I built a function that takes two arguments: the initial input text ('a') that keeps the uppercase characters as they come, and the result of the encoding, which on the other hand, has all the characters in lowercase (say, 'c'). (I'd already written all of this, and didn't have time to modify a lot, so needed something quick and in one place). so the function scans 'a', registering the positions of each uppercase character, and puts all the respective indeces into a list 'b'. Then the function scans the 'c' list and modifies it in place per the indeces, doing .upper() where needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored the code you posted as an answer, let me know if I understood things correctly.

```py
from typing import List


def copy_case(a: str, b: str) -> str:
    res_chars: List[str] = []
    curr_a: str
    curr_b: str

    for curr_a, curr_b in zip(a, b):
        if curr_a.isupper():
            curr_b = curr_b.upper()
        else:
            curr_b = curr_b.lower()
        res_chars.append(curr_b)

    return ''.join(res_chars)


print(copy_case('tEXt', 'xTTe'))
```

Comment: I think the zip is perfect for this

Comment: @Daniel Yes, `zip()` is an extremely practical function, great for parallel iteration like this.

Answer (score 2):

`.index` just returns the first occurrence of a character in a string - this has nothing to do with caches. It seems like you just want the list of numbers from 0 until your string length-1:

```
b = list(range(len(a)))
```

You do not mention why you need this, but it's pretty rare to need something like this in Python. Note in Python 3 `range` returns a a special type of it's own representing an immutable sequence of numbers, so you need to explicitly convert it to a list if you do actually need that.

Comment: ".index just returns the first occurrence of a character in a string - this has nothing to do with caches." -- so that was it then. Thank you!

Comment: Python 3 `range` is not a generator. `The range type represents an immutable sequence of numbers`. For example I can do `>>> range(1, 10, 2)[2]` which i couldn't do for a generator

Comment: @jamylak You are correct, seems like I have had a long running misconception. Editing this in, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for the input. I did figure it out with enumerate, actually. 
To elaborate, I had two lists, a and b. a contains both uppercase and lowercase characters. b consists of the same characters as a, but shifted by a certain number of positions, like in a cipher. 
I wanted to keep the case of the characters in b at the same position, after the 'encoding', but I needed the index of each character in 'A'.

Anyway, it was as simple as this:

```
a = 'tEXt'
c = [x for x,y in enumerate(a) if y.isupper()]
b = ['x', 't', 't', 'e'] #(this is the encoded version of 'a', returned from a different place as a string, but converted here to a list)
for x in c:
  b[x] = b[x].upper()
b = ''.join[b]
b 
  'xTTe'
```

Comment: Next time try asking with exactly what you are trying to do, your question will likely be better received, and answers more concrete. For example, it seems like only a single comprehension is needed for your `b`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to build a dictionary, iterating over the distinct letters in the string and using [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to obtain the index of all occurrences in the string. So going step by step:

```
import re
a = 'string of letters'
```

We can find the unique letters in the string by taking a set:

```
letters = set(a.replace(' ',''))
# {'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'l', 'n', 'o', 'r', 's', 't'}
```

Then we could use a dictionary comprehension to build the dictionary, in which the the values are a list generated by iterating over all match instances returned by `re.finditer`:

```
{w: [m.start() for m in re.finditer(w, a)] for w in letters}

{'i': [3],
 'o': [7],
 'f': [8],
 'l': [10],
 'g': [5],
 'e': [11, 14],
 't': [1, 12, 13],
 's': [0, 16],
 'n': [4],
 'r': [2, 15]}
```

Answer (score 1):

A dict is probably better than a list for this purpose:

```
foo = {x : [] for x in a}   #creates dict with keys being unique values in a
for i,x in enumerate(a):
    foo[x].append(i)        #adds each index into dict
```

for example for string `'abababababa'`:

```
{'a': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], 'b': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to get a list of the indeces of each input char as 
an output. So, for `s`, you would get [0, 16], or something along those lines.

So for each input char, you would add its position to the right list.

Storing the results in a dict seems like a good approach, so, something like:

```
def index_dict(stringy):
    d = {}
    for index, char in enumerate(stringy):
        if char not in d:
            d[char] = []
        d[char].append(index)
    return d
```

The `index()` method always finds the first occurrence. You need to find all occurrences. So, the above func will give you a dict with all the keys matching the chars of your input string, and then the value for each key is a list of indeces where that char is found.